# How to retrieve videos from server and play it onclick?

Tags: php, html, html5-video

I am doing a tutorial website project. In this i hav a video player at the right side, and vertical menu at the left side of the page. I hav lots of videos to put in. I am trying to play the videos in the same video player in the same page. How to retrieve videos from database and play it onclick from menu?

I am using video tag for video player. Also i wanted to display the video name at th bottom of the video player in the page, that changes for every videos. Like youtube website!!. I am using Wamp local server. Below is the code for single static video and video name.

```
<div class="video" align="right"><video id="movie" class="video" width="800" height="520" title="franklin" data-uid="movie" controls poster="images/LMS.JPG"><source src="videos/Learning Management System.mp4" /></video></div>

<div id="video_heading"><p><b>Introduction to Learning Management System</b></p></div>
```

How to make use of database system to retrieve the video and name of the video using PHP. Please help. I am desperately in need of someone's help.

Answer (score 1):

Use [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) to send a request from JavaScript to your server to [retrieve the correct video information from the database](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and return it in a format that you can use, like [JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). Then, using the response data, [update your video object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.setAttribute) and [other DOM elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.textContent) accordingly.

Comment: i do not know everything but only the basics of html, css, php. Can you please help me how to go about t? i am really in need of this. Please, tell me how can i proceed? is there any tutorial available for this? :(

Comment: Step 1: Click the links I provided.
Step 2: Read them.